# Calculate total distance between multiple points

Tags: rust

Is there a more efficient/idiomatic way to calculate the total distance between multiple points?

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=60c95a1c6f0e7719e653520fe0227e6e

input: `calculate_distance("100 100 200 200 300 300")`

output: `282.842712474619`

```
fn calculate_distance(vertices: &str) -> f64 {
    let vertices: Vec<_> = vertices
        .split_whitespace()
        .filter_map(|s| s.parse::<f64>().ok())
        .collect();

    vertices.windows(4).step_by(2).fold(0.0, |total, p| {
        let (x1, y1, x2, y2) = (p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);
        total + ((x2 - x1).powf(2.0) + (y2 - y1).powf(2.0)).sqrt()
    })
}
```

edit: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4f7553fcd97db2957b3963dc5476920d

Comment: Really the only things I'd change would be to return an error if the input is malformed, instead of just silently filtering non-numbers out (although I'm guessing you're stuck with the function signature) and maybe factor out the logic for calculating the distande between just two points into its own function.

Comment: well, you could have actual types for the points, so your funtion do not work over `&str` but instead some `&[Point]`

Comment: @MattWright If the number of points is fixed, you can put them into an array and pass that in as a slice.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have an inherent constraint that the input string is formatted like "x<sub>0</sub> y<sub>0</sub> x<sub>1</sub> y<sub>1</sub>...x<sub>n</sub> y<sub>n</sub>". A more idiomatic solution would be to first parse this "structured" string into an array of `Point` structs that you define, and do so outside of `calculate_distance()`. Then have `calculate_distance()` operate on an array of `Point`s.

The idea here is that it is the responsibility of the parsing code to deal with bad input. By allowing `calculate_distance()` to operate on a more tightly constrained type than `&str`, it greatly reduces the number of ways the function could go wrong.

Comment: Can this be improved still? (ignoring error handling) 

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4f7553fcd97db2957b3963dc5476920d

Comment: Hmm, maybe it would be a good idea to have some sort of Point pair, something like Vec<(Point, Point)>? Since (I'm assuming), it makes no sense to have an odd number of points? My thinking is to try to leverage the type system to describe the structure of the input as best you can. If you can strictly define what you want with types, this allows more issues to be pushed to compile time rather than runtime errors, or at least constrains where in the code runtime errors can occur.

Comment: I tried (Point, Point) using tuple_windows(), but it would require me to clone each point (possibly hundreds for each calc). My theory was tuples() will return "None" if there is not a full pair. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54441cfd717248a67d8627f684cd6804

Comment: Instead of building points and then making a tuple, make the Point tuple at the same time you create the Points: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=82416eb773995c2ed0b92b3a49cd612f